# How to store text field input as a variable for textToImage function?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm on the making an app and I can't store a text field value as a variable. It's seems easy but I couldn't solve.
Basically I just write something on textbox then hit enter and after choosing/taking picture the the text must be on the picture.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet weak var CustomerTextBox: UITextField!

var example = ""
@IBAction func EnterButton(sender: UIButton) {
    example = CustomerTextBox.text  
}

    func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {
    ImageDisplay.image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage; dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


    if let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage {
        ImageDisplay.image = textToImage(example, inImage: image, atPoint: CGPointMake(10,10))
    }

    dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


}
```

I put only interested parts of code. If needed I'll put all.

Comment: You want to get the text from TextField and assign it to the label ?

Comment: is your label will fill with textFiled data in it or not ???

Comment: @UmairAfzal with this code I do what you say. But I want assign a variable for the textbox input. After that I'll print it on to the picture. Actually it's my idea. If there is no need to store value it'd be better.

Comment: I am asking you a question, That do you want the text of textField to be displayed on label ?

Comment: if yes then just create a variable like var example = "" and then assign text of textField to this variable after user inputs the text in textField assign that text to this variable. and use it any where

Comment: @UmairAfzal No. I don't need it.

Comment: I am sorry i am not abel to understand your actuall probelm

Comment: @UmairAfzal I changed the question. Maybe you can understand now. Choosing picture, writing something, hit enter then the text will be printed on the picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

write

CustomerLabel.text!     instead     "TEXTMUSTBEHERE"

i hope this is what you want .If not please explain more